# Hot to use Algolia Places integration with react-instantsearch?

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

Does somebody have somewhere a simple Component example of Algolia Places used with [react-instantsearch](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/Getting_started.html) ?
I am desperately trying to mix the two of them, but I can't figure out what to use :  ? how ?
It's [written in the docs](https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#instantsearchjs) that [we should have a HTMLInputElement as a required container option](https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#options), so how do you deal with React where you shouldn't be able to touch the DOM ?

Cheers
Arnaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting for Algolia to develop their own stuff, a simple solution exists, [built here](https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/issues/1158#issuecomment-381544784) :

1. Go to https://www.algolia.com/users/sign_up/places to get an API Key and an API Id (it's the most difficult part actually, as getting to this URL naturally on Algolia's website is so difficult that I didn't succeed yet).
2. Get [algolia-places-react](https://github.com/kontrollanten/algolia-places-react), which is the package most customisable.
3. Fill in your options as per the Read Me, and you're good to go !

Answer (score 0):

There is no sample available yet; However you can take a look at a few non-official implementations:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-places-autocomplete
https://www.npmjs.com/package/algolia-places-react
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-algolia-places
```

We'll be building an official one soon.